# a parameterless ctor exist but unity goes to another one while resolving

Tags: c#, unity-container

I get the following error while:

```
 mConsumerTokenManager = (IConsumerTokenManager)container.Resolve(typeof(IConsumerTokenManager), null);
```

even though I have

```
public class InMemoryTokenManager : IConsumerTokenManager, IOpenIdOAuthTokenManager
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> tokensAndSecrets = new Dictionary<string, string>();


public InMemoryTokenManager(){}

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Ugi.Server.Authentication.Consumers.InMemoryTokenManager"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="consumerKey">The consumer key.</param>
    /// <param name="consumerSecret">The consumer secret.</param>
    public InMemoryTokenManager(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerKey))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("consumerKey");
        }

        this.ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
        this.ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;
    }
```

> ```
> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.IConsumerTokenManager", name =
> ```
>
> "(none)".
>       Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>       Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
>       -----------------------------------------------
>       At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> ```
>   Resolving Ugi.Server.Authentication.Consumers.InMemoryTokenManager,(none)
> ```
>
> (mapped from
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.IConsumerTokenManager, (none))
>         Resolving parameter "consumerKey" of constructor Ugi.Server.Authentication.Consumers.InMemoryTokenManager(System.String
>   consumerKey, System.String consumerSecret)
>           Resolving System.String,(none)

Comment: See http://scottdepouw.com/blog/telling-unity-which-constructor-to-use-when-initializing-a-class/, also http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2008/10/28/specifying-injection-constructor-using-unity-fluent-interface-for-loose-coupling-and-poco/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a target class contains more than one constructor, Unity will use the one that has the InjectionConstructor attribute applied. If
>   there is more than one constructor, and none carries the
>   InjectionConstructor attribute, Unity will use the constructor with
>   the most parameters. If there is more than one such constructor (more
>   than one of the “longest” with the same number of parameters), Unity
>   will raise an exception.

You can use the following code during registration to tell Unity which constructor to use:

```
this.container.RegisterType<IConsumerTokenManager, InMemoryTokenManager>(new InjectionConstructor());
```